# What is the difference between findById and findByPKCOLUMN though both return same results?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

JpaRepository method has two type of methods for fetching records from a table using Primary Key

1. `Optional<EmployeeEntity> findById(String employeeId)` - return type is optional of entity and
2. `EmployeeEntity findByEmployeeId(String employeeId)` - return type is entity

Procedure 1 requires an extra step of getting the entity from optional using optional.get().
Is there any difference and which do you recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Spring actually calls `EntityManager.find` method in the first case. This is so called direct fetching. As for the second case, spring generates jpql query. This is, so called, [derived query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods).

You can faced with difference in regard to eagerly fetched associations. See [this section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-direct-vs-query) of the hibernate documentation.

Also, if you are going to use the functionality of hibernate [@Filter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-filter), you should remember that filters apply to entity queries, but not to direct fetching.

If you are going to use [FetchMode.JOIN](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetchmode-join), you should know that `FetchMode.JOIN` strategy would be overridden by the query fetching directive.

And I believe you can find also a lot of such distinction in behavior through the hibernate documentation.